# Why does this crash at use of a null reference parameter, and not where it is initialized?

Tags: c++

I tested the following code in gcc 4.8.3 and msvc v120.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

void bar(int &x)
{
    cout << "bar\n";
    int y = x; // Crash here...
}
void foo(int *x)
{
    cout << "foo\n";
    bar(*x); // No crash here...
}
int main()
{
    foo(0);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
$ ./test
foo
bar
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I expected that it would crash upon the `*x`, however it crashes when the int reference is dereferenced.  It was compiled with the following `g++ -O0 -std=c++11 -pedantic -o test test.cpp`.  Does anyone have an explanation for this behaviour?  How is the reference initialized without dereferencing the null pointer?

Comment: Because undefined behavior is just that -- undefined.

Comment: Undefined behaviour can do whatever it darn well pleases.

Comment: Have you run `g++` with `-S` to see what assembly the compiler is generating? What the other commenters are saying about undefined behaviour is technically correct but from a practical perspective, a reference is going to be implemented as a pointer. You can initialize a pointer to NULL without crashing. It's the dereference that causes the crash. And you are confusing initialization (`bar(*x)`, which is practically equivalent to `bar((int *)0)`) with dereferencing (`int y = x`, which is equivalent to `int y = *((int *)0)`).

Comment: Since dereferencing a `nullptr` is UB, it's simply not defined where it will crash, or if it will at all. Your fridge might explode, that's what's the nature of _'Undefined Behavior'_!

Comment: Setting adide the entire notion of undefined behaviour, why do you think there should be a segfault there? Which memory access should trigger it?

Comment: Dereferencing NULL is undefined in general, but is very strongly defined for specific platforms.  For example, x86-64/Linux when configured in a standard configuration does not allow 0 in a processes VM, and will therefore segfault when NULL is dereferenced.

Comment: @Seamus: You're referring to dereferencing at the machine code level. That is, reading or writing to an invalid memory location. In C++ terms, dereferencing does not necessarily result in a memory read or write. For example, when storing the result of a dereferenced pointer in a reference, there is no need to look at the location which the pointer points at. In your case, a read of that location doesn't happen until `int y = x;`

Answer (score 0):

In case of undefined behavior nothing can be predicted. Anything could happen. The program may run as per your expectation or it may erase your hard disk!!